# onChange is resetting state - useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm not new to ReactJs but somehow when I console.log in my component function it shows that already set properties are also reset. below is my complete functional component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Grid, Typography, Paper, TextField,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import SomeComponent from '../../common/SomeComponent';
import countries from '../../utils/countries_data';
import AlertMsg from '../../utils/Alert';
import { MarkRequired } from '../style';

const App = ({ classes, handleNext, handlePay }) => {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    address1: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => setContact({
    ...contact,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });
  console.log('above splitAddressProperties', contact);
  const splitAddressProperties = (data) => {
    console.log('func start', contact);
    const country = countries.filter(
      (count) => count.alpha2 === data.country_code || count.alpha3 === data.country_code,
    );
    setContact({
      ...contact,
      address1: data.address,
      city: data.city,
      zip: data.zip,
      country: country[0],
    });
    console.log('func end', contact);
  };


  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography className={classes.inputText}>Contact Information</Typography>

        <Grid container style={{ marginBottom: '15px' }}>
          <Grid item xs={6} style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }}>
            <Typography className={classes.inputTitle}>
              First Name
              <MarkRequired>*</MarkRequired>
            </Typography>
            <input
              className={classes.inputsty}
              value={contact.firstName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} style={{ paddingLeft: '10px' }}>
            <Typography className={classes.inputTitle}>
              Last Name
              <MarkRequired>*</MarkRequired>
            </Typography>
            <input
              className={classes.inputsty}
              value={contact.lastName}
              type="text"
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="lastName"
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid style={{ marginBottom: '15px' }}>
          <Typography className={classes.inputTitle}>
            Address
            <MarkRequired>*</MarkRequired>
          </Typography>
          <SomeComponent
            className={classes.inputsty}
            value={contact.address1}
            onChange={splitAddressProperties}
          />
        </Grid>
      
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default App;
```

if I enter the first and last name and enter SomeComponent value `splitAddressProperties` is triggered but it shows that contact's value is as same as default. thing to note is that   console.log('above splitAddressProperties', contact); fires two times when first andd last names are entered.

Comment: `console.log('above splitAddressProperties', contact)` shows the correct contact values ?

Comment: yes ... but before entering the func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'ts not enough information to really find the problem, but I'm guessing that SomeComponent stores and uses an old reference of the onChange prop.

For example:

```js
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    // ...
    const innerOnChange = useCallback(
        (data) => {
            props.onChange(data);
        }, 
        // Note that the deps array doesn't have onChange:
        []
    );
    // ...
}
```

What I would do is access the current contact from the setState:

```js
setContact(currentContact => ({
    ...currentContact,
    address1: data.address,
    city: data.city,
    zip: data.zip,
    country: country[0],
}));
```

`setContact`'s reference will never change and it will always give you the current contact object. (But it's better to fix `SomeComponent`)

Comment: Can you please explain that better? I know my code is keeping an old reference since I changed the message I log to the console and the hot refresh didn't work on that onChange referenced function.

axios.post(UPLOAD_URL, data, config).then(function (res) {
     const {data} = res
     if (props.onFileAdded)
      props.onFileAdded(props.index, data)
    })
  
The passed props.onFileAdded is using old values of my state vars. how do I fix that?

Comment: I just posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211523/state-from-usestate-using-old-value-on-a-callback