# state (from useState) using old value on a callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with a file upload component that calls a `props.onFileAdded` callback when the upload ends.

```
axios.post(UPLOAD_URL, data, config)
        .then(function (res) {
            const {data} = res

            if (props.onFileAdded)
                props.onFileAdded(props.index, data)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

My issue is that my `indexList` state is reset when that callback is executed (`onFileAdded` is passed as the `onFileAdded` property):

```
const [indexList, setIndexList] = useState()
//... 
function addItem() {
    logger.debug("indexList was: ", ": ", indexList?.length, ":", indexList)
    const newIndexList = indexList == null ? [] : [...indexList]
    newIndexList.push(newIndexList.length)
    logger.debug("indexList became: ", newIndexList.length, ": ", newIndexList)
    setIndexList(newIndexList)
}

function onFileAdded(index, uploadedFile) {
    logger.debug("onFileAdded called")
    addItem()
}
```

To double check my problem I added in the parent component a button

```
    <Button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</Button>
```

And when I click that button, my state is updated as expected, but when I upload a file it is reset:

```
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList was:  :   : 
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList became:  1 :  0
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 Rendering with index list:  0
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList was:  :  1 : 0
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList became:  2 :  0,1
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 Rendering with index list:  0,1
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList was:  :  2 : 0,1
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList became:  3 :  0,1,2
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 Rendering with index list:  0,1,2
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 starting to upload
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 file load finished
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 onFileAdded called
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList was:  :   : 
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 indexList became:  1 :  0
_app.js?ts=1625147479051:16572 Rendering with index list:  0
```

I found an answer here, but I can't figure out what to do
[onChange is resetting state - useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508230/onchange-is-resetting-state-usestate)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because the `addItem()` function has an old reference to your `indexList`

From the [react docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

Try changing your `addItem` function to this:

```
function addItem() {
  setIndexList((oldIndexList) => {
    logger.debug("indexList was: ", ": ", oldIndexList?.length, ":", oldIndexList)
    const newIndexList = oldIndexList == null ? [] : [...indexList]
    newIndexList.push(newIndexList.length)
    logger.debug("indexList became: ", newIndexList.length, ": ", newIndexList)
    return newIndexList;
  })
}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know this form of setState
Then I have a paranoid question :-) is it predictable in which cases I have to do this workaround in my code? it's a lot of boilerplate if we can't use our local variables no?

Comment: We use this when our new state is derived from old state. Only this syntax would have the "freshest" value of the old state